# AWS - Importing Cloudflare certificate - where to get Certificate chain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I'm trying to import a certificate generated in Cloudflare into AWS. Coludflare provided me with the certificate and private key, but AWS also requires a field called "certificate chain". Where can I get this value?

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/article_attachments/360037885371/origin_ca_rsa_root.pem

Comment: @asdfg - can you include a link to an article/webpage instead of a file download?

Comment: Article: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507

Comment: @Asdfg It worked. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article at https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507, you can get the PEM file from https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/article_attachments/360037885371/origin_ca_rsa_root.pem and use it in `certificate chain` field.

Comment: Gitlab has a detailed step on how to append this root.pem certificate from Cloudflare. The same step can be applied for AWS. https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/02/07/setting-up-gitlab-pages-with-cloudflare-certificates/#step-4-the-trick